# Pass self as argument within init method in Swift 1.2

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

The following class has a '`let`' property declared as implicitly unwrapped variable. This previously worked with Xcode 6.2:

```swift
class SubView: UIView {

    let pandGestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer!

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.pandGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "panAction:")
    }

    func panAction(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

After updating to Xcode 6.3 (with Swift 1.2), the following compilation errors occur:

```
Property 'self.panGestureRecognizer' not initialized at super.init call
Immutable value 'self.panGestureRecognizer' may only be initialized once
```

Moving the following line before the `super.init` call:

```
self.pandGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "panAction:")
```

gives the following error:

```
'self' is used before super.init call
```

The property '`panGestureRecognizer`' requires no mutation, therefore it has to be declared as constant '`let`'. Since it is a constant, it has to have an initial value upon declaration, or initialize it within the `init` method. To initialize it, it requires to pass '`self`' in the '`target`' parameter.

Other thread suggested to declare it as implicitly unwrapped optional, and initialize it after the `super.init` call. This previously worked until I updated to Xcode 6.3.

Does anybody know a proper implementation or a workaround for this case?

Comment: This looks like a bug in the implementation, or even a specification, of the language. It's a good idea to file a bug report with Apple. Unfortunately, that is what you get when you sign up for beta-testing of a brand-new programming language that happens to be relatively complex.

Comment: It does not have to be declared as constant let. In fact, if you're going to declare it at the top of your file as an optional, you need to declare it as var so you can instantiate it in the init method.

Comment: @rdelmar you can declare let variables it just enforces that they are instatiated before the super.init.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**The Problem**

The problem is your use of `let` - optionals declared as `let` aren't given a default value of `nil` (`var` is however). The following, introduced in Swift 1.2, wouldn't be valid otherwise since you wouldn't be able to give `myOptional` a value after declaring it:

```
let myOptional: Int?

if myCondition {
    myOptional = 1
} else {
    myOptional = nil
}
```

Therefore, you're getting the error 'Property 'self.panGestureRecognizer' not initialized at super.init call' because before calling `super.init(coder: aDecoder)`, because `panGestureRecognizer` isn't `nil`; it hasn't been initialised at all.

**The Solutions:**

**1.** Declare `panGestureRecognizer` as a `var`, meaning it will be given a default value of `nil`, which you could then change after calling `super.init(coder: aDecoder)`.

**2.** In my opinion, the better solution: don't use an implicitly unwrapped optional and declare `panGestureRecognizer` with an initial value of `UIPanGestureRecognizer()`. Then set the target after `super.init` is called:

```
class SubView: UIView {
    let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer()

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        panGestureRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: Selector("panAction:"))
    }
}
```

Comment: I like your second solution. It works well for this case where you can at a later part of the code.

Comment: I like and prefer your second solution. It works well for this case where you can set the target at a later part of the code. 

For some other cases, however, there might not be a chance to do it this way. For example, lets replace the `panGestureRecognizer` with `UIDynamicAnimator`. In this case, the reference view can only be set upon creating the instance (e.g. `self.animator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: self)`.

Comment: That's a good point. In that situation you'd probably have to use a variable, implicitly unwrapped optional and set it's value after `super.init`. Or, you could use a `lazy` variable - have a look at Robert Vojta's answer. Also, if you feel this, or any of the answers solved your problem, could you consider marking one as correct.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `self` unless the class is initialized. And if you would like to use `self` for property initialization, it must be `lazy`. But `lazy` is not supported for `let`, just `var`.

That's because:

> You must always declare a lazy property as a variable (with the var
>   keyword), because its initial value might not be retrieved until after
>   instance initialization completes. Constant properties must always
>   have a value before initialization completes, and therefore cannot be
>   declared as lazy.

It's kind of compromise and if you can live with private setter, you can do this:

```
class SubView: UIView {

  private(set) lazy var panGestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer = { [unowned self] in UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "panAction:") }()

  required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
  }

  func panAction(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
  }
}
```

Or initialize `panGestureRecognizer` with just `UIPanGestureRecognizer()` and add target later.

Answer (score 3):

A workaround for this specific case would be:

```
class SubView: UIView {

let pandGestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.pandGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer()
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.pandGestureRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: "panAction:")
}

func panAction(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    // ...
}
```

}

Comment: Yep, this is what I was going to say. The let variable shouldn't stop you from adding a target after it is instantiated.

Comment: Using let doesn't stop you adding a target after it is instantiated?

Comment: That's right, using let doesn't stop you adding a target after it is instantiated. Since `UIPanGestureRecognizer` is a mutable instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass self to initializer of an object, you should declare your object as lazy. Because when this object is initialized, self is not ready yet.

```
lazy var viewModel = IntroViewModel(controller: self)

class IntroViewModel {

    private weak var controller: IntroViewController?

    init(controller: IntroViewController?) {
        self.controller = controller
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem for a different reason, it had nothing to do with Optionals or lazy. Just literally that the `person` object had to be initialized once.

```
class Person {
    var name: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

class Account {
    static let shared = Account(person: Person(name: "Bobby")) // <-- person initialized once
    let person: Person = Person(name: "Lio") // initialized again!

    init(person: Person) {
        self.person = person
    }
}
```

It's quite interesting that Swift can catch this error