# Property 'self.*' not initialized at super.init call

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6.3.1

I just updated my xcode to 6.3.1. The problem is I got this weird error message since Swift 1.2. I got this kind of error message

```
/Users/MNurdin/Documents/iOS/xxxxx/Library/SideBar.swift:32:15: Property 'self.originView' not initialized at super.init call

/Users/MNurdin/Documents/iOS/xxxxx/Library/SideBar.swift:38:20: Immutable value 'self.originView' may only be initialized once
```

on this code

```
let originView:UIView?

override init() {
        super.init() //error here

    }

    init(sourceView:UIView, menuItems:Array<String>){
        super.init() //error here
        originView = sourceView //error here
```

Comment: This could be your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29631800/pass-self-as-argument-within-init-method-in-swift-1-2/29632026#29632026

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have to initialize all property before you call `super.init` in any init method

So,change this before you call super.init()

```
originView = sourceView //error here
```

Exception:

1. optional property
2. property with default value
3. lazy property

Comment: I already initialize my property. check my question. Still error.

Comment: This answer doesn't quite seem to match the code in the question.  The problem in this case isn't where the value is being assigned, the problem is that you can't declare an optional property with `let`.

Answer (score 16):

Make your `originView` nullable by

```
var originView: UIView?.
```

If your `originView` is not nullable you have to provide a default value before calling

```
super.init().
```

Comment: let originView:UIView!. you declared originView as constant using "let". it should "var". when you are using "let" you wont be allowed to change it's value again other than during declaration.

Comment: you are correct, sorry my mistake. let me try first.

Answer (score 6):

From Apple's “The Swift Programming Language” book:

“Swift’s compiler performs four helpful `safety-checks` to make sure that two-phase initialization is completed without error”

“A designated initializer must ensure that all of the “properties introduced by its class are initialized before it delegates up to a superclass initializer.”

Basically you have to `ensure that your instance variables are in a consistent state` before you do anything, including calling methods.

```
class YourClass {
    var view: UIView
    init(view: UIView) {
        self.view = view
    }
}
```

well in your case you can make it a **new UIView**:

```
let originView = UIView()
```

or make it **nullable**

```
let originView: UIView?
```

or make a **lazy property** instead:

```
lazy var originView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 375, height: 200))
    // customize it
    return view
}()
```

when using lazy instantiation you can pass a method:

```
lazy var originView: UIView = self.createView()

func createView() -> UIView {
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 375, height: 200))
        // customize it
        return view
}
```

Comment: What is a better practice? Use *nullable* or *lazy* property?

Comment: @Edgar it depends really. There's no best way, you need to think how your class should behave, what states should it have and depending on the info you write code. Try to describe your classes on paper first and then code, soon you'll do everything in your mind automatically.