# Trouble subclassing SCNScene

Tags: swift, scenekit

I've been trying to subclass SCNScene as that seems like the best place to keep my scene related logic. Now I'm not sure wether that's reccomended so my first question is - Should I be subclassing SCNScene, and if not why not? <strike>The documentation seems to suggest it's common but I've read comments online that suggest I shouldn't subclass it.</strike> Scrap that, I was looking at the documentation for `SKScene`. The `SCNScene` class reference makes no mention of subclassing.

Assuming it's ok to structure my game that way, here's my progress

```
//  GameScene.swift

import Foundation
import SceneKit


class GameScene: SCNScene {

    lazy var enityManager: BREntityManager = {
        return BREntityManager(scene: self)
    }()

    override init() {
        print("GameScene init")
        super.init()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }


    func someMethod() {
        // Here's where I plan to setup the GameplayKit stuff
        // for the scene
        print("someMethod called")
    }

}
```

Note: I'm using `lazy var` as per the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29890510/property-self-not-initialized-at-super-init-call)

In my view controller, i'm trying to use GameScene like this

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        // create a new scene
        let scene = GameScene(named: "art.scnassets/game.scn")!

        // retrieve the SCNView
        let scnView = self.view as! SCNView

        // set the scene to the view
        scnView.scene = scene

        // Should print "someMethod called"
        scene.someMethod()
    }
}
```

However, the call to `GameScene.someMethod()` triggers an `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS` error.

Also, if I omit the call to `GameScene.someMethod`, the scene loads correctly, but the overridden initializer in `GameScene` doesn't appear to be called.

I'm not sure what's going on here. It's clear there's something about subclassing in Swift that I've not understood. Or perhaps there' some aspect of order in which things are meant to run that I've missed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Should I be subclassing `SCNScene`, and if not why not?

No, you don't need to subclass, and you're probably better off not subclassing. `SCNScene` is more like basic data/model classes (`NSString`, `UIImage`, etc) than like behavior/controller/view classes (`UIViewController`, `UIControl`, etc). That is, it's a general description of or container for something (in this case, a 3D scene) and doesn't really provide behavior. Since there's not much in the way of behavior, there's not much opportunity to override behavior with a subclass. (Nor is the class designed around subclass entry points meant to be overridden, like `viewDidLoad` and whatnot.)

While it's *possible* to subclass `SCNScene`, you don't gain much from doing so, and some APIs might not work as you expect...

> However, the call to `GameScene.someMethod()` triggers an `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS` error.
>
> Also, if I omit the call to `GameScene.someMethod`, the scene loads correctly, but the overridden initializer in `GameScene` doesn't appear to be called.

A `.scn` file is actually an `NSKeyedArchiver` archive, which means that the objects inside it have the same classes that were used to create it. when you call `init(named:)` on your `SCNScene` subclass, the superclass' implementation eventually calls through to `NSKeyedUnarchiver` `unarchiveObjectWithData:` to load the archive. Absent some unarchiver mangling, that method will instantiate a `SCNScene`, not an instance of your subclass.

Because you don't get an instance of your subclass, your subclass initializers aren't called, and attempting to call your subclass' methods results in a runtime error.

<sup>Aside: Why is SpriteKit different from SceneKit here? `SKScene` is a bit of an odd duck in that it's neither a pure model class nor a pure controller class. This is why you see a lot of projects, including the Xcode template, using an `SKScene` subclass. There are drawbacks to this approach, however — if you don't plan carefully, it gets too easy to wed your game *logic* tightly to your game *data*, which makes expanding your game (say, to multiple levels) require tedious coding instead of data editing. There's a [WWDC 2014 session on this topic](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014-608/) that's well worth watching.</sup>

#### So, what to do?

You have a few choices here...

1. Don't subclass. Keep your game logic in a separate class. This doesn't necessarily have to be a view controller class — you could have one or more `Game` objects that are owned by your view controller or app delegate. (This makes especially good sense if your game logic transitions between or manipulates the content of multiple scenes.)
2. Subclass, but arrange to put the stuff from an unarchived `SCNScene` into an instance of your subclass — instantiate your subclass, load an `SCNScene`, then move all children of its root node into your subclass' root node.
3. Subclass, but force `NSKeyedUnarchiver` to load your subclass instead of `SCNScene`. (You can do this with [class name mappings](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedUnarchiver_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000838-SW6).)

Of these, #1 is probably the best.

Comment: Good comments. I would say go with #1 and #2 where needed. But remember that in order to do #1 you need a scene to put the contents of a loaded scene into – which is where #2 comes handy.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. Combined with Hal's answer, it's filled in a lot of blanks. While the Apple Docs and online tutorials are great, as a SceneKit noob it feels like there's too little to time spent addressing how all the pieces *should* fit together.

Answer (score 3):

tl;dr: Extend `SCNNode` to generate your scene programmatically.

This started as a comment on Rickster's excellent answer but I could see it getting too long. I taught a course this quarter that spent a substantial amount of time on SceneKit. We subclassed `SCNScene` all the time and didn't run into any trouble.

However, after spending an hour just now reviewing the code I presented, the code the students wrote, and a ton of other sample code (from Apple and from other developers), I would not subclass `SCNScene` again.

None of the Apple sample code subclasses `SCNScene`. That should be a very strong clue. Handling the serialization (`initWithCoder` and the read from file) is a recurring question on StackOverflow. That's a second strong clue that you don't want to go there.

In all of the code I reviewed that subclassed `SCNScene`, the reason to do it was to generate the scene programmatically. That's Rickster's choice #2. But none of that code really needs to be on `SCNScene`. If you're building a bunch of nodes in particular configurations, adding lighting and look-at constraints, and setting up materials, it feels like you're building an `SCNScene`. But really you're building a tree of `SCNNode` instances.

So I think in hindsight, choice #2 does not provide a good enough reason to subclass. All of that construction can be done by writing a generator function, in an extension to `SCNNode`.

It's tempting to subclass `SCNNode` for this custom tree. Don't do it. You'll be able to save it and read it just fine (assuming you write the appropriate NSSecureCoding functions). But you will be unable to open your scene with the Xcode Scene Editor, because the Scene Editor doesn't know how to unarchive and instantiate your custom SCNNode subclasses.

Comment: Well put. And if you have a collection of `SCNNode`s, what you really have is just *data*... there's no reason to built it in code every time your app runs. Build it once in code and archive it to an `.scn` file, or build an `.scn` file with the scene editor in Xcode.

Comment: Isn't SCNScene subclassed in Apple's sample code project, Bananas, specifically in AAPLGameSimulation.h?